# Are 2 simultaneous webcam windows possible with openCV?

Tags: c, video, opencv, video-processing

I am applying common image transforms to my live webcam capture. I want to display the original webcam in one window and the image with the transforms applied to in another window. However, I am getting same image (filtered) on both windows, I am wondering if I am limited by the `OpenCV API` or if I am missing something? My code snippet looks like -

```
/* allocate resources */
cvNamedWindow("Original", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
cvNamedWindow("Filtered", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
CvCapture* capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(0);

do {    
    IplImage* img = cvQueryFrame(capture);
    cvShowImage("Original", img);           

    Filters* filters = new Filters(img);
    IplImage* dst = filters->doSobel();
    cvShowImage("Filtered", dst);

    cvWaitKey(10);      
} while (1);

/* deallocate resources */
cvDestroyWindow("Original");
cvDestroyWindow("Filtered");
cvReleaseCapture(&capture);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its possible! Try copying *img* to another *IplImage* before sending it to processing and see if that works first.

Yes, I know what you're going to say. But just try that first and see if it does what you want. The code below is just to illustrate what you should do, I don't know if it will work:

```
/* allocate resources */
cvNamedWindow("Original", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
cvNamedWindow("Filtered", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
CvCapture* capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(0);    

do {    
    IplImage* img = cvQueryFrame(capture);
    cvShowImage("Original", img);           

    IplImage* img_cpy = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img), 8, 3);
    img_cpy = cvCloneImage(img);

    Filters* filters = new Filters(img_cpy);
    IplImage* dst = filters->doSobel();
    cvShowImage("Filtered", dst);

    /* Be aware that if you release img_cpy here it might not display 
     * the data on the window. On the other hand, not doing it now will
     * cause a memory leak.
     */
    //cvReleaseImage( &img_cpy );  

    cvWaitKey(10);      
} while (1);

/* deallocate resources */
cvDestroyWindow("Original");
cvDestroyWindow("Filtered");
cvReleaseCapture(&capture);
```

Comment: aargh! doesn't work, on second thought, I notice the last cvShowImage() is what is shown on both windows, so if I move cvShowImage("Original") below cvShowImage("Filtered"), I start getting Original on both windows, and Filtered disappears!

Comment: There was a bug in the code, I fixed it. I'll take a look at this later. I already done this in the past, maybe not exactly like this but I know its possible to do so.

Comment: okay, it worked! actually I had passed the copy to the Filters constructor myself, but I was not doing cvCreateImage(), I wonder why do I need it, wouldn't cvCloneImage() allocate new storage while cloning and return pointer to new location already?

Comment: I'm not sure. Anyway, don't forget to vote up my answer if it helped you or accept it as the official answer if it solved your question.